# macOs app is not awakening after being closed but still remains in dock

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

I created a simple app for Mac but I faced with a strange behavior: After I click the 'close' button at the top left the app disapeared but the icon still remains active in dock. When I am trying to click this icon app is not showing again. To open it again I need to force stop in and the open it. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default behaviour of closing a window on mac applications is to just close the window, and not to terminate the app. If you want to terminate the app in this case, you need to add the following method to the app delegate (`AppDelegate.swift`):

```
func applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed(_ sender: NSApplication) -> Bool {
    return true;
}
```

There are other ways of accomplishing it, but this is the simplest.

Answer (score 0):

Try relaunching the Finder.

1)Hold down *option* key and click the *Finder* Logo in the dock with two fingers.

2)click *relaunch*